# How to set carousel slider view in mobile view display only 2 slides and desktop view 4 slides?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Is using bootstrap the best way, or any suggestions and examples?

```
  <div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify bootstrap carousel for mobile and tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238861/how-to-modify-bootstrap-carousel-for-mobile-and-tabs)

Comment: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when you say "mobile view" you mean small hand held device, add the class "hidden-xs" to the slides you **don't** want to display.

Answer (score 0):

You can use breakpoints object alongside your autoplay, Like this

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  autoplay: {
    slidesPerView: 2,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  breakpoints: {
    1024: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 50,
    },
  },
});
```

Here Is The Documentation Example For Responsive Sliders

https://codesandbox.io/s/3blv5?file=/index.html